# Which of the following sets, operations and constants can be used to define a Boolean Algebra?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

The problem with this question is I don't quite understand it, or rather how to think about the question. It's a multiple choice question and below are a couple of the options:

(a)

- $T = \{n|n>0$ and $n|8\}$
- $x\land y = $ gcd$(x,y)$
- $x\lor y = $ lcm$(x,y)$
- $x' = 8/x$
- Zero $= 1$
- One $= 8$

(b)

- $T = \{n | n>0$ and $n|30\}$
- $x\land y =$ gcd$(x,y)$
- $x\lor y =$ lcm$(x,y)$
- $x' = 30/x$
- Zero $= 1$
- One $= 30$

These are just two of the options but how do I know if (a) or (b) can be used to define a Boolean algebra?

Comment: You have to verify if the [axioms for boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Definition) hold for the suggested examples. Example : 1) *Commutativity*: $x \lor y = y \lor x$ and the same for $\land$. Is it true that $\text {lcm}(x,y)=\text {lcm}(y,x)$ ? and the sane for $\text {gcd}$.

Comment: Yes to both LCM and GCD. I think I understand now. How about stuff like "Zero $= 1$" and "One $= 8$"? How do I apply the axioms to those?

Comment: Same thing… What are the axioms involving $1$ ? E.g. $x \land 1 = x$. Thus for (a) with $\text {One}=8$, you have to check that $\text {gcd}(x,8)=x$ for every $x$.

Comment: What is the domain of values for $x$? Is it "Zero" and "One", namely 1 and 8?

Comment: @WilliamElliot can you explain how or why?